# Lambda or itemgetter aren't working for sorting the righ part of a list

Tags: python

i did a lot of research but i can't find how to apply these solutions to my code after many hours.

I have a simple list

```
pommes : 30
bananes : 20
oranges : 13
citrons : 5
kiwis: 90
```

I am trying to sort by numbers in from the highest number to the lowest with this code `sorted([list],key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`

I have also tried sorted`(unsorted_list, key = itemgetter(1))` while calling `from operator import itemgetter`

im giving you my code so you can understand my situation better

```
                message2 = sorted(ligne(texte))
                for j in message2:
                    parts = j.split(":")
                    gauche = parts[0].strip()
                    droite = parts[1] if len(parts) == 2 else 0
                    print(gauche, ":", droite)
                break
```

---

this is the part of the code i think sort should go

```
       for j in message2:
            parts = j.split(":")
            gauche = parts[0].strip()
            droite = parts[1] if len(parts) == 2 else 0
            print(gauche, ":", droite)
        break
```

expected results:

```
kiwis: 90
pommes : 30
bananes : 20
oranges : 13
citrons : 5
```

Ive tried to sort ligne(texte) didn work its never getting sorted. I've been told i was because my lis is a sring? but when i try to sort droite, droite is an int

Comment: What is `list`?

Comment: is it a list or a dictionary?

Comment: You don't have a list. You've just printed a bunch of stuff.

Comment: this is a list!

Comment: line(text) is my list im importing from a function

Comment: You should post a [mcve], without the definition of your variables your example isn't complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex to pull out the digits and wrap that in a lambda that converts it to an integer. Then your sort will work for any length of value.

```
>>> mylist = """pommes : 30
... bananes : 20
... oranges : 13
... citrons : 5
... kiwis: 90""".split('\n')
>>> 
>>> import re
>>> mylist.sort(key=lambda val: int(re.search(r':\s*(\d+)', val).group(1)), reverse=True)
>>> mylist
['kiwis: 90', 'pommes : 30', 'bananes : 20', 'oranges : 13', 'citrons : 5']
```